# Design Patterns for project managing system

Tags: java, design-patterns, project, decorator, factory-method

I have to make "Decorator pattern" for my project called "Project managing system". This is application where lecturers can add project topics for students and students can browse, choose and make a reservation. Every student can send his progress, lecturers may assessetc etc.
I made first design pattern called "factory method" as in the picture below and my lecturer accepted this pattern for 4-th time because I made many mistakes.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKby7.jpg

I need your help with decorator pattern becasue I really don't have idea how draw this. Thanks and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

May be this link could help : http://www.dofactory.com/net/decorator-design-pattern

Comment: so we need more details... The goal of the Decorator is to add dynamically some functionalities to an object.
You have to define what the base object is, which behaviour you want to add, this sort of things